# Dynamically Update Side Menu in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a side menu in ionic 2 which I am trying to update after user logs in. I am using Events from ionic-angular. Here is what I have done.

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, Nav, AlertController, MenuController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {

  rootPage:any = HomePage;
  logoutAlert:any;
  currentUser:any;

  @ViewChild('nav') nav: Nav;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, public storage: Storage, public alertCtrl: AlertController, public menuCtrl: MenuController, public events: Events) {

    this.currentUser = {
      name: "Guest",
      username: "not logged in"
    };

    this.logoutAlert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      message: "Sure you want to log out?",
      buttons: [{text: "Yes", handler: () => {
        this.logoutUser();
      }}, {text:"No", role: "cancel"}]
    });

    this.menuCtrl.enable(false);

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  ionViewWillLoad() {

    this.events.subscribe("userloggedin", (user) => {
        this.currentUser = JSON.parse(user);
    });

  }
```

app.html

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
    <ion-item>
        <ion-avatar>
            <img src="../assets/letters/{{currentUser.name}}.svg">
        </ion-avatar>
        <p>
            {{currentUser.username}}
        </p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage" #content></ion-nav>
```

home.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { NavController, Slides, LoadingController, Events } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { HttpProvider } from '../../providers/http/http';
import { TabsPage } from '../tabs/tabs';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    @ViewChild('signSlides') signSlides: Slides;

    currentUser: any;
    loading:any;
    signinForm:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public storage: Storage, public httpProvider: HttpProvider, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, public events: Events) {
    this.signinForm = formBuilder.group({
        email: [''],
        password: ['']
    });

    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: "<ion-spinner></ion-spinner>"
    });
  }

  signinUser() {
    let params = {
        username: this.signinForm.value.email,
        password: this.signinForm.value.password
    };
    this.httpProvider.loginUser(params).subscribe(
        results => {
            this.loading.present();
            this.currentUser = results['_body'];
        },

        err => {
            alert("Oops! An error occured!");
        },
        () => {
            this.storage.set("currentUser", this.currentUser);
            this.loading.dismiss();
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
        }
    );
  }

    this.httpProvider.registerUser(params).subscribe(
        results => {
            this.loading.present();
            this.currentUser = results['_body'];
        },
        err => {
            alert("Oops! An error occured!");
        },
        () => {
            this.storage.set("currentUser", this.currentUser);
        this.events.publish("userloggedin", this.currentUser);
            this.loading.dismiss();
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(TabsPage);
        }
    );

  }

  firstLetter(s:string) {
    s = s.toLowerCase();
    return s.charAt(0);
  }

}
```

I have tried putting events.subscribe in ionViewDidLoad, ionViewDidEnter and ngOnInit but nothing has worked for me. The data from home.ts is being saved in the storage but I can't figure out why doesn't it upadte in the ionic menu.

Comment: It is a comment, not an answer - I would suggest trying Redux pattern with, for example, ngrx, and manage all aspects of the state in a central place. Then your component, in this case MyApp, would subscribe to the user state, and display the logged in user name, or some default string if no user is logged in. I am fresh from doing it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is suggested to pass a string value to the event, instead of a Json object,
`this.events.publish("userloggedin", this.currentUser`);`
If **this.currentUser** is a string in the above piece of code in your home.ts, then it should work as you expect.
And also in app.component.ts,inside the constructor, you may put your code in this way.

```
this.events.subscribe("userloggedin", (user) => {
    this.currentUser = user
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The `app.component` doesn't have the same callbacks as other pages, so you have to move your code to the class constructor:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  constructor(private events: Events) {
    this.events.subscribe("userloggedin", (user) => this.currentUser = user);
  }
}
```

You don't need the `JSON.parse(user)` since Events doesn't convert the object to string.